# Flutter Chart: How to make multiple duplicated domain as one by merging and adding Firebase data together?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using import 'package:d_chart/d_chart.dart' to do the graphs list.

[Current Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBZ6V.png)
As seen, the pie chart looks missing due to the inclusion of the first document of the data from Firebase.

If there are two documents or more containing fields (x-axis) that have the same value, how do I merge them as one by combining them for both graph chart and pie chart?

My expected output of the value of totalprice is, first value: 23, second value: 24, third value: 25.
These 3 values (Field name: totalprice) belong the same name of another data field called state.

By merging them together within the same state, the totalprice value will be 72.

My Code:

```
class Statistics extends StatelessWidget {
  final String year;
  final String month;
  const Statistics(this.year, this.month, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<DataObject> chartData = [];
    return Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('Transactions')
                .doc(year)
                .collection(month)
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                
                List moneyChart = snapshot.data!.docs.map((e) {
                  return {
                    'domain': e.data()['state'],
                    'measure': e.data()['totalprice'],
                  };
                  
                }).toList();
                if (snapshot.data!.docs.length == 0) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: Text("Unavailable"),
                  );
                } else {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            const Text("Revenue of State Statistics"),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                              child: DChartBar(
                                data: [
                                  {
                                    'id': 'Bar',
                                    'data': moneyChart,
                                  }
                                ],
                                axisLineColor: Colors.black,
                                barColor: (barData, index, id) => Colors.cyan,
                                barValue: ( barData, index, ) =>
                                    '${barData['measure']}',
                                showBarValue: true,
                                barValuePosition: BarValuePosition.auto,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            const Text("Passenger of State Statistics"),
                            AspectRatio(
                              aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                              child: DChartPie(
                                data: snapshot.data!.docs.map((e) {
                                  return {
                                    'domain': e.data()['state'],
                                    'measure': e.data()['passenger'],
                                  };
                                }).toList(),
                                fillColor: (pieData, index) {
                                  switch (pieData["domain"]) {
                                    case 'Perak':
                                      return Colors.grey;
                                    case 'Kedah':
                                      return Colors.red;
                                  }
                                },
                                labelPosition: PieLabelPosition.outside,
                                labelColor: Colors.black,
                                labelFontSize: 14,
                                labelLineColor: Colors.amberAccent,
                                labelLineThickness: 2,
                                labelLinelength: 20,
                                labelPadding: 5,
                                pieLabel: (Map<dynamic, dynamic> pieData,
                                    int? index) {
                                  return '${pieData['domain'] ?? ''}: ${pieData['measure'] ?? ''.toString()}';
                                },
                                showLabelLine: true,
                                strokeWidth: 2,
                                donutWidth: 15,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                }
              } else if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text("Unavailable"),
                );
              } else {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text("Loading"),
                );
              }
            }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```